# How can I edit more than one radio button in a loop in laravel

Tags: laravel

How can I edit more than one radio button in a loop in laravel

```
  <?php $i = 1; ?>
                            @foreach ($products as $product)

                                <tr>
                                    <td scope="row">{{ $i++ }}</td>

                                    <td>{{ $product->name ?? '' }}</td>
                                    <td><img src="{{asset($product->image)}}" class="product-img-2" alt="product img"></td>
                                    <td>
                                  <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$product->id}}">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="status[{{$product->id}}]" value="active" {{($product->status  == 'active') ? 'checked' : '' }} id="Active">
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="Active">
                                                active
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="status[{{$product->id}}]" value="deactive" {{ ($product->status == 'deactive') ? 'checked' : '' }} id="Deactive" >
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="Deactive">
                                                deactive
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                  </div>

                                    </td>

                                </tr>


                            @endforeach
```

public function active_deactive(Request $request){

```
    if (isset($request->status)) {
        foreach ($request->status  as $status_id) {

            $product =   Product::where('id', $request->id)
                ->update(['status' => $request->status]);
        }

    }
    

    return Redirect()->back();
}
```

How can I modify more than one radio button as shown in the picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU3GF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$request->id` is going to be the last `id`, since you've got multiple `<input name="id">` elements. You need to send them as an array:

```
<input name="id[]" value="{{ $product->id }}">
```

Then reference them on the backend:

```
foreach ($request->input('status') as $key => $status) {
  Product::where('id', $request->input('id')[$key])->update(['status' => $status]);
}
```

Or, since you already have `name="status[{{ $product->id }}]"`, you can just use that instead:

```
foreach ($request->input('status') as $productId => $status) {
  Product::where('id', $productId)->update(['status' => $status]);
}
```